# Round of a half cut cylinder with subsurf

Tags: modeling, modifiers, faces, normals, subdivision-surface

im trying to model a half cut cylinder with an axial cut section. The Cylinder has a subsurf modifier. As long as the cylinder is cylindrical, it is perfectly round (Type A). If i remove the half of the cylinder using a boolean operation, it stays round (B). But if i remove the verts in edit mode, the shape is no longer round (C ):
[image]
[image]

Is there a way to model a shape like C without a boolean modifier? The problem is that the cylinder i part of a larger model, and if i cut it, the topology gets destroyed:
[image]

Using the Boolean Modifier alone is not a solution as the model should be low poly and be exported into another application.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Have you tried adding control loops close to the edge where the distortion happens?

Comment: Likely faces on the cut ending change the edge flow and cylinder doesn't appear to be round. After Boolean (or manual cut, sometimes is best) delete faces on the mirror plane like on the first screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a cylinder;
2. Apply E and S to the bases and delete created faces. Remove doubles;
3. Join the edges with Bridge Edge Loops to make inner faces. The result should look as below;
   [image]
4. In face selection mode select, with B, and delete half of the cylinder created thus;
5. Make faces where the crossection was made (see the image below);
   [image]

Done.

If you want you may make more quads with Ctrl+R

Comment: Hi Lukasz, You are right with your answer. I did the same method before, but i had to less verts on the circle circumference. Try your method with only 6 or 8 verts on the circumference, and it will fail at subdiv level 3. Anyway, your method is usefull. Thanks a lot!